# Why do I get a segfault in C from declaring a large array on the stack?

Tags: c, stack

I get a segfault from this line of code:

```
int fatblob[1820][286][5];
```

Why is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a stack overflow exception when declaring a large array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571945/getting-a-stack-overflow-exception-when-declaring-a-large-array)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a big array in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137598/create-a-big-array-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a stack overflow exception when declaring a large array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571945/getting-a-stack-overflow-exception-when-declaring-a-large-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Segmentation fault on large array sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to allocate `1820 * 285 * 5 * sizeof(int)` bytes = about 10MB (if `sizeof(int) == 4`). That's probably more bytes than your OS gives you for stack allocation by default, so you get a stack overflow/segfault.

You can fix this by either asking for extra stack when you create the thread, allocating on the heap, or changing the OS defaults.

Answer (score 8):

Because your stack segment is smaller then `1820*285*5` `int`s. It's usually in a neighborhood of 1MB.

Comment: * sizeof(int), over 9MB on a sane, 32-bit system.

Answer (score 3):

Because stack overflows. Try to allocate that array on the heap.

Answer (score 3):

```
int fatblob[1820][286][5];
```

you are trying to allocate a memory location of 180*286*5*4 (let size of int = 4) that is around 9.8 MB, so there is a possibility of having lesser default stack size on your OS.

LINUX has 8192 KB(i.e. 8 MB) of stack size. So obviously you will be getting a stack overflow if you are trying to allocate more memory on stack.

You can try changing the stack size of your OS.
In LINUX you can try **ulimit**

ulimit -s < whateversize you want it to be>

like

**$ ulimit -s 1024**

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic variables (the default type) in C are usually allocated on the stack. The stack is a memory region allocated per thread, and while it may grow on many operating systems, it always has a limited size. [danben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144135/why-do-i-get-a-segfault-in-c-from-declaring-a-large-array-on-the-stack/3144165#3144165) covers the default stack pretty well, but if you're using threads, you're allocating new ones in thread creation (e.g. pthread_attr_setstacksize). In general, large allocations are better done on the heap (malloc/new), but even that may be too small sometimes. mmap() or similar sometimes help then.

Where did danben's answer go? It linked to [some information on stack limits](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt).