# Segmentation fault in C while declaring large pointer array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow, large-files

I run in a problem with a program and I'm not sure how to solve it. I'm processing a file and to do so I get the size with ftell and store it in M_size. After that I declare a unsigned char pointer array with N. The array is then used in two functions a() and b().

```
...
unsigned long N = (M_size/ x);
int LstElemSize = M_size % x;
if(LstElemSize != 0){
    N += 1;
}    
unsigned char *ptr_M[N]
a(ptr_M)
b(ptr_M)
...
```

Function a() actually initializes each element of ptr_M in a for loop:

```
a(){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < N-1; i ++){
     ptr_M[i] = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * x);
  }
 }
```

Function b() iterates then over each element and calculates stuff and at the end each element is freed.

My problem is now that when I try to process a file e.g. 1 GB the array size will be around 4 000 000 and a Segmentation error occurs (In the line i declare my array). If I calculated it correctly that is 8 byte (char pointer) times 4 000 000 = 32MB. The server running the program has enough memory to hold the file, but i guess as mentioned in [Response 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283546/segmentation-fault-while-creating-large-arrays-in-c) the stack space is not enough.

What can I do to solve my problem? Increase my stack space? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to create a 32MB array on the stack? The stack is usually in the single-digit MB range, on Windows using VC++ the default is only 1MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're defining ptr_M in the stack, which has a small size limit. The heap does not have such a small size limit and is able to use more of your system's memory. You need to use malloc() to allocate ptr_M just like you allocate the subarrays. (Make sure to free it at some point too along with all those subarrays!)

```
unsigned char **ptr_M = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*) * N);
```

Also, your `a()` has an off-by-one error. It ignores the last item of the array. Use this:

```
  for(i = 0; i < N; i ++){
```

Comment: You're right about the off-by-one error but actually I'm doing something else with the last element. But without any context you're absolutely right!

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned char *ptr_M[N]` is a [variable-length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) declaring `N` number of `unsigned char` on the stack in your case. You should dynamically allocate the space for the array as well.

```
unsigned char **ptr_M = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*) * N);
a(ptr_M);
b(ptr_M);
...
//After you free each element in ptr_M
free(ptr_M);
```

Comment: I would upvote this too for the free hints, but I can't. Hope someone else will do it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

malloc allocates space from heap, not from stack. You may try increasing your heapsize looking at the compiler option. Check the upper limit of heapsize that is supported there.