# Can't locate two-dimensional array of chars in c with length 1000000

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to create a two dimensional array of character in c program as:

```
char array[1000000][10];
```

but the program output "Segmentation fault" in the runtime. I tried to create it with 100,000 and it worked, but 1,000,000 didn't work. What is the reason that makes this line of code causes Segmentation fault?

Comment: That's almost ten MB, normally a stack is in the single-digit range. Windows, for example, only have 1MB stack by default.

Comment: @m.s.: It is not a duplicate because one is about C and the other about C++.

Comment: Many other duplicates though, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144135/why-do-i-get-a-segfault-in-c-from-declaring-a-large-array-on-the-stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably overflowing your operating system's idea of how large a stack can be, assuming it's a local variable inside a function.

That array will require 1000000 * 10 = ~9.5 MB of stack space, which is quite a lot.

Try:

- Making it `static`.
- Using `malloc()` instead.
- Modifying OS-level limitations.
- Making it global. Of course global variables are bad, so this is the worst solution in many cases.

Comment: Option 4: Use a `static` array.

Comment: global variables are never a good option

Answer (score 0):

That is about 10 megabytes. You are probably trying to define the variable as function local variable. Stack is usually not that big. Use dynamically allocated memory instead.