# How to get number of elements in the array of pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

How to get number of elements in array of pointers?

Below is my code:

```
struct mystruct     
{    
  int a;    
  char ch[10];    
  int c;    
};

mystruct *m_arr[2];
```

I am traversing this array in some other files. Instead of hard-coding as 2 in every file I want to get the number of elements in the array programmatically.

Comment: You're programming in C++. So use `std::vector`.

Comment: Or `std::array<mystruct,2>` if the size is really fixed. Either way, pick a language. You're using a mix of C and C++ here.

Comment: std::begin and std::end should work for arrays as well

Comment: @AndrewKashpur: Wouldn't work with `extern mystruct *m_arr[ ]`. This question just contains the definition of `m_arr`, but there is only one Translation Unit with the definition. The rest o the code deals with the declaration.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use raw arrays.  Use a standard container like `std::vector` or `std::array`.  Both of these have a `.size()` member, and allow the range-based for syntax:

```
    for (mystruct* p : m_arr)
```

If you need C compatability, they both offer a `data()` member function which returns a pointer to the first element in the underlying array.  (In your case, that will be a `mystruct **`)

---

Edit: A raw array also supports the range-based for syntax - but *only* if the visible declaration includes the number of elements (so `my_struct* m_arr[2];` is fine, but `my_struct* m_arr[]` would not work).  It is impossible to declare a `std::array` without defining the size too. 
 Other containers (like `std::vector`)
 don't include the size in the declaration.

Answer (score 6):

The usual way of doing this is:

```
size_t sizeOfArray = sizeof(m_arr)/sizeof(m_arr[0]);
```

About `size_t` from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types):

> size_t is an unsigned integer type used to represent the size of any object (including arrays) in the particular implementation. **The sizeof operator yields a value of the type size_t**. The maximum size of size_t is provided via SIZE_MAX, a macro constant which is defined in the  header (cstdint header in C++). size_t is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits wide.

Comment: On some platforms you can use the `_countof` macro: `size_t sizeOfArray = _countof(m_arr)`;

Answer (score 4):

If this is a header file included by all other source code files using `m_arr` you can use `sizeof(m_arr)/sizeof(m_arr[0])` to obtain the number of elements in the array. But this is really dangerous. If at some point the pointer `m_arr` enters a function as a parameter the scope of the function will not return 2 at `sizeof(m_arr)` but the number of bytes which the pointer takes in the memory which probably is 8.

So if you want to stick to plain C then you have to pass the number of elements in a separate variable. But if you can use C++ there is a variety of better, safer and even faster solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You can always do such memory arithmetics:

```
size_t arraySize = sizeof(m_arr) / sizeof(m_arr[0]);
```

But if you don't have a reason like in [*When would you use an array rather than a vector/string?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/594542/2754173):

Then you should use a `std::array<mystruct*, 2> m_arr;`, the size of which you can access through `m_arr.size()`, and the address of the *underlying native array* you get with `m_arr.data()`.

Answer (score 1):

In C++17 you can `#include <iterator>` and use `std::size(m_arr)`.

Comment: Or implement it in C++14 yourself (not an overly complex construct). I don't believe it depends on any core language changes in C++17.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have your array as the following:

```
char *array[3];
```

Add an extra item to the array, which is considered to serve as an array terminator.

```
char *array[3]={"First element","Second element",""};
```

The rest of it depends on your own coding style, you can check for the terminator and count the number of elements except the terminating string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use std::vector, but if you must...

this works for c++11 or greater:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t sizeofArray(T(&)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

Saw this recently in a video about [7 Features of C++ You Can Adopt Today](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wnj6M-jj9c)